# マンデルブロ集合の自己相似点を自動検出していい感じの画像を生成したい

Tags: アルゴリズム

マンデルブロ集合を使った画像生成システムを作るにあたって、図中の拡大箇所を自動で検出してくれるような機能を付けたいと思っています。
その際に、出力される画像を出来るだけ複雑な図柄にするために、マンデルブロ集合内の自己相似点を自動検出してそこを拡大していくようなアルゴリズムを考えているのですが、その具体的なコードが思い浮かびません…。
自分は数学がてんでダメなもので、言語は問いませんのでなるべくコードとして具体例をご教授いただけますと助かります。

マンデルブロ集合の描画、拡大、カラーリングなどに関しては調べたらいくらでもコード例はあるのですが、
「拡大箇所を自動検出する」となるとMisiurewicz points、Feigenbaum pointsのような数式を理解してコードに落とし込むしかないのか…と苦戦してます

Comment: 最初に人が「ここの部分（絵柄の範囲）と相似な部分を探せ」のように指示するのでしょうか？　それとも「ここの部分」という範囲も自動で決定されるという話なのでしょうか？

Comment: 別サイトの質問 https://teratail.com/questions/gpsnx9pmo8d5pt は非表示化されてしまったために放棄されたのかもしれませんが，マルチポスト的になっている旨は一応述べるのが良いのではないでしょうか．

Comment: 既にカラーリングを行なっているようなので、「いい感じ」に拡大することが目的ならば自己相似を検出しなくとも、複数の色が十分に使われている箇所を使用するだけでもよいかも知れません。

Comment: @mjy 確かにカラーリングをしていればどの箇所を切り出してもいい感じと言えばいい感じなのですが、やはりマンデルブロ集合らしいフラクタルが感じられる境界線付近を狙って拡大していきたいという意向です。“いい感じ”という定義が曖昧で申し訳ないです。

Comment: @fana マルチポストにより各所に混乱をきたしてしまいすみません。おかげさまで自分の求める解決策に至りましたので、それをここにご報告させていただきます。お付き合いいただきありがとうございます。

Answer (score -2, accepted):

https://qiita.com/satouta310ta/questions/e086a18e8f7e74c7898d
こちらにて自分の求める解決策に至りましたので閉めさせていただきます。ご解答にご協力いただきありがとうございました。

Comment: 他のマルチポスト先で解決した場合、単にリンクを指し示すだけなのは回答として不親切です。各サイトごとに「個別の回答」として内容が成り立つような投稿を心がけてください。

Answer (score 0):

失礼しました。
私の知る範囲で、可能性のある方法を記載いたします。
「２次元データの画像から、自己相似点を検出する」には、次のふたつの方法が考えられます。

(1)機械学習（テンプレートマッチング）を利用する
OpenCVに利用できそうな機能がありました。
https://shikaku-mafia.com/opencv-template-match/
OpenCVおよびnumpyは、以下のコマンドでインストールできます。

```
pip3 install opencv-python
pip3 install numpy
```

上記でエラーが発生する場合は、
https://www.kkaneko.jp/tools/ubuntu/opencv.html
OpenCVそのもののインストールが必要かもしれません。（←あいまいな記憶ですいません。）

このリンク先のコードを実行した結果を添付します。
(threshold = 0.3に変更しました。元のフラクタル画像を、25%縮小&トリミングしたものをテンプレート画像として指定しました。)
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

(2)総当たりで比較する
「２次元データの画像から、自己相似点を検出する」方法として、総当たりで比較します。
２次元データ(元となるマンデルブロ集合の画像)から、
サイズ(高さ、幅)、位置（x、y）、さらには回転角を、変更し、
元となる画像から一部の画像を抽出し、自己相似点があるか判定します。
そのときの判定方法に、自己相関や自己相似のアルゴリズムが適用できる可能性があります。
総当たりは処理時間がかかるため、画像サイズを荒くする、回転は考慮しないなどの、工夫を別途必要とします。

//////
まずは、１次元データで、相関係数を調べてみてはいかがでしょうか？
https://data-viz-lab.com/correlation-coefficient

理解できれば、２次元データへも適用/応用できることも理解できると思います。
scikit-learnにも、自己相関を算出するメソッドが含まれているので、利用してみるとよいでしょう。

Comment: マンデルブロ集合は複素数を使っている関係で本質的に実数 2 次元になるのですが、1 次元データとはどのようなものを想定されているのでしょうか……？

Comment: まずは勉強のため、例えば日々の気温などを一次元データとして、相関度を算出してみたらよいのでなないでしょうか。２次元データの画像でも、一次元データとして扱うこと（変換すること）ができます。

Comment: さらに、距離についても理解を進めていけば、できるようになるのではないでしょうか。
<https://qiita.com/best_not_best/items/c9497ffb5240622ede01>

Comment: 自己相関と自己相似は異なる概念ですが、そこはよろしいですか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。自己相関と自己相似は異なる概念であること知りませんでした。どちらも今回の「自己相似点を自動検出」するための候補になるので、よいのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 自己相関からどうやって自己相似を見つけるのでしょうか。

Comment: 相関(自己相関ではなく、拡大するべき領域の画像との相関)のあるものは似た画像と判断し、自己相似を見つけなくてよいのではないでしょうか。
同様に自己相似のあるものは似た画像と判断し、自己相関を計算しなくてもよいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 相似なので回転や拡大縮小を含むのですが、その場合ただ相関係数を計算するだけだとうまく検出できませんよね。そのあたりはどう処理する想定でしょうか？

Comment: マンデルブロの一部を対象図形として選択したとして→それと相似な図形が現れるのにはどれほどの拡大をしないとならないのか？（そしてその際の着目位置はどこなのか？）というのが本件の問題なのではないかと思えます．　無限の解像度で描画するならばその単一の絵の上で絵的な検出が可能なのでしょうけど…

Comment: 素人なので的外れなことを言っているかもしれませんが…
マンデルブロを拡大していく系の動画みたいなのって「相当に拡大する（：本当に「点以下」みたいな全く見えていなかった範囲にズームしていく）と最初と同じ図形が！」みたいなイメージがあるので…
画像相関から見つけるしても，そのマッチング処理を実施する対象の絵に行き着く術が何かしら別途必要なのではないか？　と．